# Is it possible to force a query to ignore the server option "remote proc transaction promotion" so it doesn't promote remote proc transaction?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, stored-procedures, linked-server, remote

I have a specific query that executes a stored procedure on a remote linked server and inserts the results into a local temp table.

I don't want it to promote a remote procedure transaction but I can't re-configure the server.

Is there a query hint or some way to force it to not promote a remote procedure transactions?

Edit: The reason I ask is because I'm getting the following error when trying to execute my remote procedure call:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MyRemotelyLinkedServer" returned
>   message "The transaction manager has disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions.". Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure
>   spMyRemoteProcedure, Line 64 [Batch
>   Start Line 15] The operation could not be performed because OLE DB
>   provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MyRemotelyLinkedServer" was unable to
>   begin a distributed transaction.

I know I can set "Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions" to false on the Linked Server options to fix this, but I'm not allowed to make server option changes in this context, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a query hint or some way to force it to not promote a remote procedure transactions?

No there isn't, but if you're currently doing something like this:

```
INSERT #Temp
EXECUTE schema_name.procedure_name AT linked_server;
```

or

```
INSERT #Temp
EXECUTE linked_server.db_name.schema_name.procedure_name;
```

You could work around it using:

```
INSERT #Temp
SELECT column_list 
FROM OPENQUERY(linked_server, 'EXECUTE db_name.schema_name.procedure_name');
```

Assuming you're using a simple procedure that returns a single result set. You may also need to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the procedure as I mentioned in answer to [Using OPENQUERY to execute a script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/64947).